# Can I add some hidden text with paragraphs in MSWord

Tags: c#

I am developing a MS Word add-in using c#. The code processes some very large input file and converts it to a word document. I am able to generate data and store it in heading 1, 2, ... normal etc styles.

Now I also want to store some hidden text (containing some self-generated information) with each of these paragraphs. This hidden text should by no means be visible to someone who opens this file in MSWord. But this hidden text must be retrievable to convert this word file back to the original file. Is it possible to insert some hidden fields with each paragraph (and I want to have multiple such fields - say about 4 to 5).

I am using OpenXml to create the word file.

I am very anxiously looking for some solution. Or if it is not possible to do so, then I must look into some altogether different solution.

Comment: Is it enough to set the text to Hidden in the same way as if you used the font dialog (with the issue being the user can unhide it if they so choose)?

Comment: No, I don't want the user to be able to unhide it. Basically this data must exist unknown to the user.